# Redirecting page based on script outcome

Tags: javascript

I'm working on the following script. Basically I want to redirect a page to one of two choices, based on whether the browser has allowed a popup. I know that the following won't work because window.location needs to be called as the DOM loads, but I'm wondering if there is something I can use or if I need to rethink my approach

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openwindow(){
    var w = window.open("{INTERACTION}","interaction","resizable=0,width=800,height=600,status=0");
    if(w){window.location = "carry on.html"};
    if(!w){window.location = "blocked.html"};
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>  
<input type="submit"  class="button" onClick="javascript: openwindow()" value="Begin" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance
Giles

Comment: @Matt Ball: He's actually stating that it does not work.

Comment: Correct, I'm asking for what will work

Comment: try using it the correct way window.location.href

Comment: @Ibu both ways are correct, it doesn't make any difference if you assign either to one or another. both do exactly the same when assigned. (I'm not saying that they are the same =))

Comment: @giles do you get any errors?

Comment: yes the above fails to load in either instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't necessary to call it as the DOM loads. it works both when DOM is loading and when it is fully loaded:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        window.location = "http://google.com";
        }
</script>
```

// during DOM loading:

```
<script>
    window.location = "http://google.com";          
</script>
```

Comment: are you saying write something like ... if(w){function(){window.location = "enabled.html";}};

Comment: But that's what I'm trying about (isn't it) and it's failing. Am I missing something?